# React Native UML

Tags: react-native

I'm currently making a mobile application using React Native as an intern. My school demands me to make UML Diagrams. Does anyone know what diagrams I Could make aside from a state diagram? I couldn't really find any good example online and don't know how to model UML for react native.

I've tried to implement something like this: https://www.reddit.com/r/reactnative/comments/lchikf/check_out_my_attempt_at_a_uml_component_diagram/

But with this aproach I don't know how to have conditional components. For example I have a HomeScreen component which is a React component that returns a view with some conditional components. When I try to replicate that as component diagram conditions are not possible.

Thanks in advance!